# Is there any PHP code formatter for VSCode that complies with PSR-12?

Tags: php, code-beautification

Does anyone know a code style formatter that complies with the [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for Visual Studio Code?

I searched the web, but I can only find some plug-ins like [PHP Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Sophisticode.php-formatter) which follows the [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) which is now replaced by [PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/).

Answer (score 0):

A PHP extension I'm using on VS Code seems to be suggesting [*php cs fixer* from junstyle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=junstyle.php-cs-fixer) to format code.

The configuration example seems to say that you can comply to PSR-12:

```
{
    ...
    "php-cs-fixer.rules": "@PSR12"
    ...
}
```

There seems to be some other (sometimes outdated/deprecated) extensions when I search around for php code sniffer, but I haven't tested them.